# Flash8 Button to make screen fully blank

Tags: flash

Is there some way I can use a flash button to call some javascript?
The swf would be embedded in my html webpage.

```
on(release){

//fire javascript code to blank whole screen.

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by the whole screen? Like the whole browser window? Just the flash? The entire clients screen? You question is way too vague. Also what have you tried? What's worked and what hasn't worked?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. I think what you're looking for is [flash external interface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

there is another Little fix for this.You may append ?html5=1 to play fullScreen Video on your browser.
I have added embedded video to

```
?html5=1
```

then Video will render the HTML5 Player instead of Flash player.

Thanks.